# Why Don't I Have Tag Badges?

Tags: support, badges

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki
>   answers in the [name] tag.

I'm not sure why I haven't earned this badge yet. I have 36 up votes and 38 posts in the "real-analysis" tag for example.

Does it really mean "up votes" and not "total score"?

Comment: Somewhat related posts (and with pictures): [How to track next tag badges?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/how-to-track-next-tag-badges)

Comment: And this might also be useful to read, if you want more details: [What are tag badges? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836) and [List of all badges with full descriptions - Tag Badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Score" (as in, "the score of a post") generally refers to "upvotes minus downvotes" (i.e., the number that is displayed between the voting arrows next to the post), not the reputation that has been earned by a post.  In this context, total score means the sum of the scores of all of your non-CW answers in the tag.  So your total score in [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) is only 36, and you need 64 more score to earn the badge.

Comment: Do you know if the number reported on my profile counts community wiki posts?

Comment: The score number displayed in your profile counts only non-CW answers, so it's exactly the number that is relevant to the tag badges.  However, the displayed number of posts in a badge counts all posts, including questions and CW answers.  You can mouse over the score number to see how many of those posts are non-CW answers, as well as your number and total score from non-CW questions.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, and what I think, *point* means what we see beside our posts, i.e. *upvotes $-$ downvotes*, not the *reputation* we achieved from them.